# Get table names and print first row of each

Tags: php, mysql

How do I print the first row of each table?

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_database';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}

mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
//echo "<br>Table name is: {$row[0]}\n";

// Make a MySQL Connection
$tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM $dbname.$row[0] LIMIT 1";  
$tableResult = mysql_query($tableQuery) or die(mysql_error());

$firstRow = mysql_fetch_array($tableResult) or die(mysql_error());
//echo $firstRow['name']. " - ". $firstRow['age']."<br>";
    //how do i print field name row and first row of values 
    //if I don't know the field names


}

//mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Is this not working? What gets printed instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not changed your default db, either by doing

```
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

or doing

```
$tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM $db_name." . $row[0];
```

so your inner query is failing.

Comment: A little more direction please.  I'm a newbie.  I'm trying to print the first row of values in each table.  My previous wording may have been confusing.  The db, host, user and passwd values (ie mysql_database) are placeholders.

Comment: I get crickets.  Totally blank page results with $tableQuery line as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'the first row of each table'
but to limit the results to 1 row use

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1
```

Note: This simply gets the first row it finds, this may or may not be the first row inserted, it could easily also be the last row inserted.
There is no explicit order implied.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query like below, it will fetch 1st row in the table

```
$tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$row[0]."LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: oy! Here's the result: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: After connecting to mysql(after first if statement) write mysql_select_db($dbname); ,it will solve your error.